# ConvincingMail.AdvancedAutoSuggest.dll not working on server

Tags: asp.net, autosuggest

I'm using ConvincingMail.AdvancedAutoSuggest.dll, It's woking fine at localhost. After uploading the site on Web Server I found that autosuggest not working. But Website is running.

Please tell me what will be the reason, and solution.

(If there is no possibility, tell me the replacement of ConvincingMail.AdvancedAutoSuggest.dll)

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Debashis

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the GET and POST are disabled by default when acessing a webservice not from local. To fix this you need to add this in your web.config file:

```
in web.config file find the <system.web> section and add 
<webServices>
<protocols>
<add name="HttpSoap"/>
<add name="HttpPost"/>
<add name="HttpGet"/>
<add name="Documentation"/>
<add name="HttpPostLocalhost"/>
</protocols>
</webServices>
```

under it
For example check the demo application web.config. [more info in the forum](http://forum.convincingmail.com/yaf_topics6_Tools-Servicies-and-Controls.aspx).